# jQuery exclude div from html and body selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="div1">...</div>
        <div id="div2">...</div>
        <div id="div3">...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="other-div">...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery('html, body').on('touchstart touchmove', function(e){ 
       e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

How can I exclude `#div1` and all of its contents/children from this selector of `('html, body')`?

I tried

`jQuery('html, body :not(#div1)')`

and also

`jQuery('html, body').not( document.getElementById( "#div1" ) )`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('html, body').on('touchstart touchmove', function(e){ 
   e.preventDefault();
   var $target = $(e.target);
   var id = $target.attr('id');
   if(id != 'div1') {
     // not div 1
   }
});
```

Comment: I think you are trying to do a function if it isn't `#div1`, the function is already there, I'm just trying to exclude `#div1` from that function

Answer (score 0):

You could do like below:

```
$('body').on('touchstart touchmove', ':not(#div1)', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: may not work because [touchmove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/touchmove) bubbles like the click event - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Zpr9a/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to first select the children of html, body before you can filter with .not():

```
$('html, body').children().not($('#div1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('body').on('touchstart touchmove', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('#div1').length == 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** to prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree:

```
jQuery('html, body').on('touchstart touchmove', function(e){ 
       e.preventDefault(); 
});

jQuery('#div1').on('touchstart touchmove', function(e){ 
       e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```